# Single Table Stored Procedure Deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to increment a value in MSSQL (ex, to increment a user's balance after buying a giftcard).

My stored procedure and table look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table ([intCount] [int] NOT NULL)

ALTER PROCEDURE Test_Proc AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRAN
        UPDATE Test_Table
        SET intCount = intCount + 1 
    COMMIT TRAN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    RETURN(0)
END
```

I only have one row in the table for simplicity and I just increment all rows.

I spawn 10 threads in C# and call the stored procedure 10 times in each thread. However I get deadlocks in most of the threads. My code that calls this stored procedure looks like:

```
for (int thread = 0; thread < threads; thread++)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Test_Proc", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errors++;
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

I tried WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) but that didn't seem to reduce the frequency of deadlocks.

Is there anyway I can change the stored procedure to prevent these deadlocks? I am really looking for a SQL answer as opposed to just serializing all stored procedure calls in C#.

(This is similar to [Deadlock with single stored procedure and multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115086/deadlock-with-single-stored-procedure-and-multiple-threads), however that question is explicitly asking for how to deadlock, while I just want to avoid a deadlock).

EDIT: I modified the code to put the contents of the stored procedure in a transaction, but it still deadlocks.

EDIT: The error message looks like `Transaction (Process ID 124) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`.

EDIT: I updated the stored procedure per feedback, but it still deadlocks.

EDIT: It looks like the explanation is in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831413/1117119 . SERIALIZABLE gets a shared lock, and then converts it to a exclusive lock when it is going to write. This results in a deadlock.

Also it appears that any further deadlocks occur because I simply have too many threads: [SQL Server 2008: Getting deadlocks... without any locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465166/sql-server-2008-getting-deadlocks-without-any-locks) .

Comment: check this q/a (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41594231/1158842) seems to be the same root issue. If you want it done at the SQL level then you are likely headed to sp_getapplock

Comment: There is no need to `select` the current value first. An `UPDATE Test_Table SET intCount = intCount + 1` is enough. Ehen you say "*it deadlocks*", do you actually get an exception that one transaction was killed because SQL Server detected a deadlock? If yes, then please add the error message of that exception to your question. It is expected that the threads will wait, because you can't update the same row from multiple transactions at the same time, the second update always needs to wait for the previous one to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that what you've showed us is just a simlified version of the problem, but anyway consider whether instead of separate SELECT and UPDATE you're able to do it as a single UPDATE, ie:

```
UPDATE Test_Table SET intCount += 1
```

If this is not possible, then enclose both statement into a single transaction.

EDIT:
To avoid the convert lock deadlocks, add `with(xlock, tablock)` hint to the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the code to put the body of the stored procedure in a transaction, but it still deadlocks as often as before.

Answer (score 0):

Dean's answer is the most correct, but in the case anyone else wants to know how to make a separate SELECT and UPDATE work correctly, this is the code I ended up with:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @x int

    select @x = intCount
    from Test WITH (TABLOCKX, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE id = 1    

    UPDATE Test
    SET intCount = @x + 1
    WHERE id = 1    

COMMIT TRAN
```

This resolves the issue of the first select not taking an exclusive lock (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831413/1117119).

Also it looks like any code that acquires locks will deadlock if too many threads are created ([SQL Server 2008: Getting deadlocks... without any locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465166/sql-server-2008-getting-deadlocks-without-any-locks)).